# Find the equation of an ellipse passing through $4$ given points

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

The purpose of this exercise is to find the equation of the ellipse whose axes are parallel to the coordinate axes, and passing through $4$ given points, where it is assumed that no $3$ of them are collinear.

My effort:

The equation of the above-described ellipse is

$$ \dfrac{(x - x_0)^2 }{a^2} + \dfrac{ (y - y_0)^2 }{b^2} = 1 $$

Define $A = \dfrac{1}{a^2}$ and $ B = \dfrac{1}{b^2} $, then the equation becomes

$$ A (x^2 - 2 x x_0 + x_0^2) + B (y^2 - 2 y y_0 + y_0^2) = 1 $$

Re-arranging

$$ A x^2 + B y^2 + C x + D y + E = 0 $$

where $ C = -2 x_0 A $ , $ D = - 2 y_0 B $ , $ E = -1 + A x_0^2 + B y_0^2 $

From the above definitions, it follows that

$ x_0 = - \dfrac{ C }{2 A} $ and $y_0 = - \dfrac{ D }{2 B} $

Therefore, $E = -1 + \dfrac{1}{4} \left( \dfrac{C^2}{A} + \dfrac{D^2}{B} \right) $

And this will lead to a nonlinear system in terms of $A,B,C,D$.  To overcome this problem, and knowing that coefficient of $x^2$ cannot be zero, I divided the above ellipse equation by $A$, to obtain

$ x^2 + B' y^2 + C' x + D' y + E' = 0 $

where $ B' = \dfrac{B}{A}, C' = \dfrac{C}{A} , D' = \dfrac{D}{A}, E' = \dfrac{E}{A} $

Now there are only $4$ unknowns appearing linearly, so using the $4$ points we can find them all, by solving the $4 \times 4$ linear system:

$\begin{bmatrix} y_1^2 && x_1 && y_1 && 1 \\ y_2^2 && x_2 && y_2 && 1 \\ y_3^2 && x_3 && y_3 && 1 \\ y_4^2 && x_4 && y_4 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} B' \\ C' \\ D' \\ E' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} - x_1^2 \\ - x_2 ^ 2 \\ - x_3^2 \\ - x_4^2 \end{bmatrix} $

It follows from the above analysis that

$ x_0 = - \dfrac{1}{2} C' $

$ y_0 = - \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{D'}{B'}  $

and

$ E = -1 + A x_0^2 + B y_0^2 $

so that

$ E' = \dfrac{-1}{A} + x_0^2 + B' y_0^2 $

From this we can solve for $A$, and this also gives $B = A B' $

Now the ellipse is fully identified.

**Question:**  Is the method described above correct, and is there a simpler and more direct way ?  I look forward to any comments or suggestions or solutions.  Thank you all.

Comment: It is usually assumed that no three points are collinear.

Comment: @Siddharth I've added this detail into the question.

Comment: I have some approaches. But I didn't think it is will be straightforward,will requires a bit pages of work.